# Is there a way to specify the use of text or titling figures in CSS?

Tags: css

My fonts of choice usually default to text figures

[image: Text figures]

which is one reason I like them. However, for tables or headings I'd like to specify that lining figures should be used:

[image: Titling figures]

Is there a way to do so in CSS?

(To appease the search:

- old-style numerals, text figures, non-lining figures, medieval numerals
- lining numerals, titling figures)

Comment: I would have thought this is specific to the font. I'm not aware of anything like this in CSS.

Comment: @Jason: I would have assumed that to be common knowledge, sorry. Edited.

Comment: @Tom: The font has a default, but every good OpenType font has both variants and allows the the rendering engine to choose one or the other. After all, the context dictates the use of one variant or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox 4.0 has basic [text figure support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-font-feature-settings). Here's how to turn on text (old-style) figures:

```
.text-figures {
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "onum=1";
}
```

Looks like there's a set of css3 properties, such as [font-variant-numeric](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-variant-numeric), to control common properties. These are not yet supported by any browser, as far as I know.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/xt2Gk/1/) where you can play around with the styles. It toggles between lining and old-style figures. I'm using Minion Pro on Windows 7, so you might have to find your own supported font on other platforms.

Comment: Still a proprietary solution *sigh*. I wish, CSS would get such support, eventually.

Comment: Well, it's there, in draft form. We just have to wait until the browsers support it. I expect Firefox might be pretty quick on that one, since they already have the support -- it's just an interface change.

Comment: @Joey: IE10 supports several opentype features using `-ms-font-feature-settings`: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/OpenType/ Also see http://caniuse.com/font-feature

Comment: Marcel, note the age of the question. I know it's standardised by now.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: It's still a draft, and as you can see there is very sparse browser support. Plus, it's still somewhat unlikely for your *font* to support them. I don't know how many of the system fonts support both lining and old-style figures, but I'm sure it's not many.

Comment: @Joey: I know, my comment is merely here for reference (someone might Google it). theazureshadow: it's not only meant for system fonts, but especially for custom fonts using `@font-face`.

Comment: It's too bad that `font-variant-numeric` still hasn't caught on. :(

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such property in the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html). It's up to the web browser to chose a font available in the system and render it with whatever the ‘default’ style is.

A quick look in the [CSS 3 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/) also doesn't reveal an option like this.

And although you can use the [@font-face](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) property in [newer browsers](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_browser_support), there doesn't seem to be an option to select OpenType features in general (like using [lining or oldstyle figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType_feature_tag_list)).

A quick search revealed there has been a discussion about this on the [W3 CSS mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Oct/0293.html).

---

**Update:** Inspired by [Creating Custom Font Stacks with Unicode-Range](http://24ways.org/2011/unicode-range) I decided to give `unicode-range` property a try. Alas, you cannot change the lookup-table to use custom figures when normal figures `0-9` are used.

But, though it's not convenient to enter digits in high Unicode ranges (e.g. use the [Unicode code converter](http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/)), it *is* possible to use a specific set of figure, e.g. lining numerals for tables (and the ﬁ-ligature as well):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <title>Table numerals</title>
  <style>
   @font-face {
     font-family: Calluna;
     src: url(http://localhost/Calluna-Regular.otf);
   }
   body { font-family: Calluna }
   #f { font-size: 32pt }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p id="f">Table ﬁgures: </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm, I feared as much. It's interesting that CSS allows quite fine-grained control over typesetting in some cases and almost completely neglecting typography.

Comment: @Johannes You can, of course, use that granularity to do what you want. Using @font-face, you can define the alternate style as "Font Name Lining" or assign it as you would a completely different font.

Comment: @D_N: agreed, though @font-face is [not that widely supported](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_browser_support), yet.

Comment: I have to disagree on that. Compare that table against what's currently in use and the adoption curve of most (non-IE) browsers. You easily have a supermajority of browsers. Besides, if you're going to use a custom font at all you have to either use @font-face or something similar which will have the same limitations (Cufon, etc.).

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, `@font-face` requires me to distribute a font I probably don't have permissions distributing *and* modify it appropriately that it uses the other numeral variants by default (which I likely also don't have permission to do). So is the `@font-face` rule only for people who do both webdesign and cut typefaces (I suspect their number is vanishingly small) or where freely-available fonts can be used.

Comment: @Johannes: Unfortunately, yes. But there's hope: the [Web Open Font Format (WOFF)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/About_WOFF).

Answer (score 1):

OpenType features are now supported in many browsers:

```
font-feature-settings: 'lnum'
```

Old-style is also supported via `'onum'`. You can omit the '=1' for boolean flags.

See [Mozilla's description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) for more details, or [this more thorough writeup](http://ilovetypography.com/OpenType/opentype-features.html) of the various font features.

Comment: +1 Here is a list of possible values :
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/#article-header-id-0
Of course, the font you chose need to have those specific characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
body {
        -moz-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
        -moz-font-feature-settings:"lnum=1";
        -ms-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
        -o-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
        -webkit-font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
        font-feature-settings:"lnum" 1;
        font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
    }
```

Comment: How is this different from theazureshadow's answer from four years ago, or Alex' answer from 2 years ago?