# Can you specify tabular lining figures for webfonts?

Tags: css, typography, fixed-width, monospace

Since it's possible to specify lining and oldstyle figures I'm hoping there's browser support for *tabular* numerals with webfonts?

- Left: default numerals
- Right: desired **tabular** numerals (notice monospaced)

[image]

Font: [Brandon Grotesque](http://www.hvdfonts.com/)

Related: [Is there a way to specify the use of text or titling figures in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940259/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-use-of-text-or-titling-figures-in-css)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simply, yes.

Presently you can use the attribute "[font-feature-settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings)" in its prefixed forms and add **"tnum"** to the value list ([example](http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/feature-samples/forex.html)) to access tabular numerals in OpenType enabled fonts:

```
font-feature-settings: 'tnum';
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'tnum';
-moz-font-feature-settings: 'tnum';
```

Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-feature-settings) to see if the prefixed versions are still needed.

Note, if you are using Typekit to serve your webfonts, make sure to select "All Characters" under Language Support.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is [recommended way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) to access this OpenType feature (font-feature-settings: 'tnum' from Mark Fox's answer):

```
font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
```

I can't find anything at http://caniuse.com/#search=font-variant-numeric yet so stick with Mark's answer until browser support can be better determined.

Answer (score 6):

While it is possible *to specify* tabular numerals there is no guarantee that the end user's browser supports the `tnum` property.

The [State of Web Type](http://www.stateofwebtype.com/#Tabular%20Numbers%20(tnum)) keeps track of which browsers support these (and other) advanced typographic features.

*As of this writing* `tnum` is supported by:

- Chrome v.33-41
- Firefox v.4-39
- Internet Explorer v.10-11
- Opera v.15-28

`tnum` is not supported by:

- Safari (OSX)
- Safari (iOS)
- Android Webkit
- Older versions of the browsers listed above

Comment: I believe it does provide an answer to the question. In addition to asking how to specify tabular numerals, the OP is also asking _if there is browser support_. The link in my answer presents a table of this property's support across the modern browsers.

Comment: My view is that it does provide an answer.  The question is first "can you specify...?" - this answer says "yes".  Is there browser support? answer "not guaranteed - here's a resource that tells you which do / don't".  The info from the link could be summarised here to improve the answer - specifying from which versions the various popular browsers support.  Otherwise it is dangerously close to a "link only answer"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JRichardSnape. I've updated my answer with summarized data from the linked site. I'm new here and still getting the hang of the rules. I apologize for the incomplete answer. Cheers.

Comment: Sure, no problem, we all have to get the hang of the site at one time or another.  I hope you stick with it - it can be rewarding! All the best.